# Synopsys: get the total number of paths in the circuit

Tags: tcl, synopsys-vcs

I'm working with dc_shell of Synopsys and I'm trying to obtain the total number of paths of the synthetized circuit with a slack lesser than to a particular value. In order to do that I'm using the command:

```
get_timing_paths -slack_lesser_than <value>
```

I always get a collection of size 1. I am stuck on this problem and I don't know how to work it out.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try increasing -max and/or -nworst, both of which default to 1.  For example:

```
get_timing_paths -slack_lesser 5 -max 1000 -nworst 1000
```